# What pattern does Vue reactivity system use?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am just confuted about what pattern does Vue reactivity system are using. Observer Pattern or Pub/Sub pattern? If it uses Observer Pattern, what does the Dep do?

Comment: checkout this article to understand view reactivity.
In this article i am explaining top level view of vuew reactivity. https://sharmishtha-dhuri.medium.com/understanding-vue-reactivity-5a2e53a6b985

Answer (score 1):

They using Proxy, more detail: https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity.html#proxy-vs-original-identity